# ModuleNotFoundError: Trying to import model from models folder into a view in views folder

Tags: python, django

I am new to the Django framework and I have some questions regarding importing of modules. Below is my file structure:

```
MyLife
- MyLife
  - finance
    - models
      - __init__.py
      - category.py
    - views
      - __init__.py
      - category.py
```

I am trying to import the models.category into my views.category.

`models.__init__.py`:

```
from .base_model import BaseModel
from .category import Category
from .client import Client
from .entry import Entry
from .rule import Rule
from .wish_list_item import WishListItem

__all__ = ['BaseModel', 'Category', 'Client', 'Entry', 'Rule', 'WishListItem']
```

views.category.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from MyLife.finance.models import Category


def category(request):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'finance/category.html', {'list_categories': all_categories})
```

models.category.py:

```
from django.db import models
from .base_model import BaseModel


class Category(BaseModel):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.description
```

Here is my stack trace error:

```
  File "/Users/AKJ/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/finance/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/AKJ/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/finance/views/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . category import category
  File "/Users/AKJ/Coding/MyLife/MyLife/finance/views/category.py", line 3, in <module>
    from MyLife.finance.models import Category
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyLife.finance'
```

I am not sure what is wrong and if i am missing something out. I heard a lot about **init**.py to help reduce the namespace, however, i seem to have problems and i do not really understand the other stackoverflow explanations.

Also, should i rename my models.category into category_model.py and the views.category into category_views.py?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're missing an `__init__` at the root of the `finance` directory.

Comment: You should stick with files `models.py` and `views.py`. If you are new to Django, then follow the tutorial and practice. Once when you're comfortable using the framework, you can experiment with different approaches. Don't break the rules if you don't master them.

Comment: FWIW Python is not Java, you don't have too split your code with one submodule per model or view...

Comment: @cezar i am aware that splitting isnt necessary, however, i am just practicing and experimenting what happens if i split them up and what the possible errors are and what i can do to fix them.